# Authorization in social networking website

Tags: python, django, authorization, social-networking

I need to accomplish the following related to privileges:

I have 3 users:

```
- User A
- User B
- User C
```

Each of the users has the following documents with associated access settings:

```
- User A
    - Document A1, only allow contacts to view
    - Document A2, allow everyone to view
    - Document A3, allow no one to view except myself
    - Document A4, allow contacts, and contacts of contacts to view
- User B
    - Documents B1, B2, B3, B4 with similar privileges
- User C
    - Documents C1, C2, C3, C4 with similar privileges
```

`User A` has `User B` as a contact but is not a contact of `User C` (`User B` and `User C` are contacts).

Thus, `User A` would be able to view the following:

```
- Document B1 (contacts can view)
- Document B2 (everyone can view) 
- Document B4 (contacts of contacts)
- Document C2 (everyone can view)
- Document C4 (contacts of contacts)
```

I am interested to learn how these privileges would be handled. I am also seeking any documentation or articles that would help me hit the ground running.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "authorization".

Comment: Any links discussing authorization from a conceptual standpoint (not necessarily django-specific) would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general answer is to find the distance between the document owner and a given contact. In Computer Science terms, this is a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph).

There's a good article with some SQL queries that covers this topic at http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/09/07/graphs-in-the-database-sql-meets-social-networks/. Rather than trying to summarize the entire article, here's how to conceptualize the problem:

- Start with a blank piece of paper.
- Draw a dot somewhere on the page for each person (in this case, Users A, B, and C). In CS terms, this is a "node".
- Draw an arrow from a user to all of their contacts. In CS terms, this is a "directed edge", or an "arc".

  - This isn't explicit in the question, but it looks like User C must be a contact of User B, or a contact another of User A's other contacts (since User A can read C2 and C4).
  - So in this case, you would draw from User A -> User B, and User B -> User C.

As an aside, if being a "contact" is mutual, you can draw a line segment (or bidirectional arrow) instead of an arrow. In CS terms, this would be an "undirected" vs. a "directed" graph. Facebook relationships are an undirected relationship; if someone is my friend, then I am also their friend. By contrast, if someone is in my Outlook address book, I'm not necessarily in theirs. So this is a directed relationship.

As more users are added to the drawing, you'll notice that a user's contacts are one step away, and their contacts-of-contacts are two steps away. But you can only travel in the direction of the arrow.

So the problem for contacts is, "How do I find all nodes whose graph distance is one?" And the question for contacts-of-contacts is, "How do I find all nodes whose graph distance is two?". Although "two or less" is probably more appropriate, since you'd expect direct contacts to have access to all of the "contacts-of-contacts" content.

For the general case, there are some SQL queries described in the article that might provide some insight. But for your specific need, I'd consider just using some joins.

Let's consider a `Users` table, with primary key `id` along with its other fields, and a `HasContact` table which has only two columns: `userId` and `contactId`. We'll assume that User A has id 1, User B is 2, and User C is 3. HasContact has rows (1, 2) and (2, 3) to represent the relationships described above.

A pretty simple set of SQL joins can produce a list of all friends, or all friends-of-friends.

The following query would return all IDs of a User's contacts:

```
SELECT contact.id
  FROM Users "user"
    LEFT JOIN Relationships "rel"
      ON user.id = rel.userid
    LEFT JOIN Users "contact"
      ON rel.contactId = contact.id
  WHERE user.id = $id_of_current_user
```

If you know the user IDs, an authorization query could be quite simple:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM Relationships "rel"
  WHERE rel.userid = $document_owner_user_id
    AND rel.contactid = $id_of_current_user
```

If the query returns 0, then we know that the current user is *not* one of the document owner's contacts.

We can update that second query to indicate whether a user is a contact-of-a-contact:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM Relationships "rel_1"
    INNER JOIN Relationships "rel_2"
      ON rel_1.contactId = rel_2.userId
  WHERE rel_1.userid = $document_owner_user_id
    AND rel_2.contactid = $id_of_current_user
```

This should return nonzero, as long as there are entries in the Relationships table such that `($document_owner_user_id, X)` and `(X, $id_of_current_user)` both exist. Otherwise, it will return zero.

I know this is a long and somewhat indirect answer, so please comment if you have any questions.

Comment: apologies for not awarding you the bounty, I didn't see your response until after it had expired. But thank you very much for the link and response.

Comment: @David542, no worries on the bounty. Hopefully the info was along the lines of what you wanted.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately Django's authorization system does not allow you to assign permissions per object, only per class. Here I assume that each of your "Document" is an instance of a model class.

There are, however, reusable apps that greatly simplify this task. Have a look at [django-guardian](http://djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-guardian/) or [other packages](http://djangopackages.com/search/?q=permissions) that work on object (or row) level.

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by permissions "per object", "per row", or "per class" with an example of each? Thanks.

Comment: By "per class" I mean the default approach of django's admin and auth mechanism. If you have a model called "Document" and go to the admin page of your site, you should be able to edit an user and assign a "yourapp | document | Can add document" (and also "can change" and "can delete"). This, however, applies to all the Document instances. On the other hand, by "per object" (or "per row"), you should be able to specify the permissions (such as change,delete or others you might create) for each individual document (A1, A2, etc).

Comment: As an additional note: If your documents always have an owner and only have 4 levels of visibility (private, contacts, contacts of contacts and public), you could store the level as a field in its model and use the mechanism in @jammon 's link to enforce these 4 levels. If you think the permissions could grow more complicated in the future, you should look for a more elaborate and extensible authorisation system.

Answer (score 3):

What you basically need is to [Limit access to logged-in users that pass a test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test). But the part with "contacts of contacts" can lead to very complicated sql-queries. And I suggest you to rethink that requirement. (I have lots of good friends whom I like and trust. But they have all kinds of weird people as friends ...)

Answer (score 3):

What you need is an [access control list(ACL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) which will change according to each users network. ACL as well as object based permissions is not available in standard `django.contrib.auth` module. I've actually implemented an ACL in Django, But it's class based not object based. In the context of your application it'd work like `User A` can view anyones documents as long as he is in a certain authorized group(say `Admins` group). But it can be made to work like `User A` can view `User B`s documents If `User A` is in the `Contacts` group for `User B`.

I can explain how do it in terms of model structure for a customized auth app. The `User` and `Permission` model will be the same as standard Django auth app(You can copy it from [models.py](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/models.py)). Then you need a model to represent different levels of permissions(Everyone, ContactsOfContact, Contact, Myself). Doing this is simple as adding another field to the standard django auth groups model. This field will be a foreign key to the same model, Which will represent the group each group will inherit from. Now the model looks like this,

```
class SocialGroup(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

Now you can add relationships such as `Contacts` group can view everything that `Everyone` group can view by setting `Everyone` group as the parent to `Contacts` group. Note that there's no foreign key relationship with `Permission` model. Next we need a way to specify the relationships between users and groups.

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
  user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
  related_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  related_by = models.ForeignKey(SocialGroup)
```

With this model we can say `User A`(related_user) is related to `User B`(user) by being in `User B`s `Contacts`(related_by) group. Then we need a way to specify permission for each document.

```
class DocumentPermissions(models.Model):
  document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
  group = models.ForeignKey(SocialGroup)
  Permission = models.ForeignKey(Permission)
```

Now we can say `Contacts` group has `can_view` permission for `Document B1`. Note that this model should go to wherever the Document model is located NOT to auth models.py in our new auth app. That's it, Now all we have to do is to write the logic to find permissions for a given user for a given document. So here's what we need to do when a `User B` tries to view `Document A1`,

- First check which person the document belongs to(`User A`)
- Then find the relationship group between owner and the one trying access the document from Relationship model(Contacts).
- Then check `DocumentPermissions` to see whether that group or any group that it inherits from has permissions to view the document.

This logic can be implemented in a new authentication backend(which will use our new auth models) for Django which can go into the new auth app. You can check `has_perm` function in standard [Django model backend](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/backends.py). That's all you need to do. All the decorators and stuff will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a "friends of friends" field. It would be a very big table (say, 200*200*N = 40,000*N ... or really huge if you have no limit to friends, and someone is friends with a million people - that's 1 million people with 1 million FoF) but it would be easier than hitting the database 200 times per view.